# Why form displays <? print $_POST['domain']; ?> instead of the empty text field

Tags: php

I have this input field, which is part of a whois search script.

`<input type="text" name="domain" value="<? print $_POST['domain']; ?>" />`

On the form, instead of displaying an empty text field, it displays `<? print $_POST['domain']; ?>`.

Could someone please tell me what's going on here?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Changing `<?` to `<?php` helps?

Comment: please improve your question.It's hard to understood and also put your code here

Comment: I agree with Yan. `<?` is shorthand for `<?php` but is not enabled by default on all servers. Try using the full `<?php` at the beginning of each php code block instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
<? print $_POST['domain']; ?>
```

Change to

```
<?php print $_POST['domain']; ?>
```

Please consider that this way of output is unsafe, if someone can change the variable then its a potential XSS threat.

To prevent this use:

```
<?php print htmlspecialchars($_POST['domain']); ?>
```

Comment: Hi all. Thanx for your replies. The code comes from a whois script i'd purchased to use on my website. I've added the code under my original post

Comment: changing <? to <?php did help

Comment: <div id="demo">
<form method="post" class="whoisform" action="<? print $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" onSubmit="return validateDomain(this.domain)"><span style="position:relative;top:-1px;">www.</span><input type="text" name="domain" value="<? print $_POST['domain']; ?>" />.
<?
renderTLDList();
?>
 <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
</div>

Comment: Thanx guys. Changing it as suggested above did the trick. All seems ok now

Comment: Ok, strange things are happening now. In my code, two comments up, I changed <? to <?php in all instances. When I change the last one (<? renderTLDList(); ?> to <?php renderTLDList(); ?>) then the submit button disappears.

I think its also something on my local server, wamp, apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.3 and mysql 5.5.24.

Thanx

Comment: Then its maybe that the output of the renderTLDList(); method is falsy... go to the sourcecode of your website and examine the details (right click: show sourcecode)